# how can i know resource requested before executing filter?

Tags: jakarta-ee, filter

how to know resource request before redirecting(using filter)   an Example : when i make request in facebook group and i am not logined &after i login it redirects me to the my first request how  can i implement that in java enterprise edition ???

Actually i made three servlets one for login , one for home and one for group link as example  and if he correctly login i make session then redirects him for home 
i wanna when he requests any servlets that need session to be in redirects him to login and if it is true  **Redirect him to requested resource before login**

Answer (score 0):

> if he correctly login i make session

And that's where you're wrong: you assume that Facebook doesn't store anything about your activity until you're logged in.

So the answer is: make every servlet store its request to the session before you redirect to the login screen, so after the login was successful you can read the last request from the session and redirect there.